# ComponentDidMount was not called

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to fetch data with Redux and Thunk. I don't know why code that perfectly work in the other components stop to work in this one - state just do not receiving correct data because function that should call server just was not fired in ComponentDidMount.
Component.

```
class SparePartDetails extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const path = this.preparePath(this.props.location.pathname)
        this.props.fetchDetails(path);
    }

    preparePath = (path) => {
        const segments = path.split('/');
        const filter = segments.length > 2 ? segments[2] : '';
        const id = segments.length > 2 ? segments[3] : '';
        return `${Constants.apiUrl}/${Constants.paths.spareparts}/${filter}/${id}`;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <h1> <FontAwesomeIcon size='xs' icon='cog' /> Детали запчасти</h1>
                <main className={styles.details_container}>
                    <section className={styles.flex}>
                        <h2>Фотографии</h2>
                        <SparePartImages id={this.props.details[0].Id}/>
                    </section>
                    <section className={styles.flex}>
                        <h2>Описание</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Название: {this.props.details[0].Name}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Чертежный код: {this.props.details[0].BlueprintCode}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Категория: <NavLink 
                                    className={styles.navigation__item__link} 
                                    activeClassName= {styles.active} 
                                    to={`/spareparts/categories/${this.props.details[0].CategoryId}`}>
                                    {this.props.details[0].Category}
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Производитель: {this.props.data.Manufacturer}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Единица измерения: {this.props.details[0].Unit}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Количество в упаковке {this.props.details[0].ItemsPerPack}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Длина. В упаковке: {this.props.details[0].LengthInPack} / Без упаковки: {this.props.details[0].LengthNoPack}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Глубина. В упаковке: {this.props.details[0].DepthInPack} / Без упаковки: {this.props.details[0].DepthNoPack}
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Высота. В упаковке: {this.props.details[0].HeightInPack} / Без упаковки: {this.props.details[0].HeightNoPack}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                    <section className={styles.flex}>
                        <h2>Кто продает</h2>
                        <SparePartSuppliers id={this.props.details[0].Id}/>
                    </section>
                </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
 }

export default withRouter(SparePartDetails)
```

Container

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  details: console.log(state.sparepartdetails.data),
  loading: state.sparepartdetails.loading,
  error: state.sparepartdetails.error
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchDetails: path => dispatch(fetchSparepartDetails(path))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SparePartDetails)
```

Actions

```
export const fetchSparepartDetailsBegin = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.sparePartDetailsActions.FETCH_DATA_BEGIN
});

export const fetchSparepartDetailsSuccess = sparepart => ({
    type: ActionTypes.sparePartDetailsActions.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
        sparepart
    }
});

export const fetchSparepartDetailsFailed = error => ({
    type: ActionTypes.sparePartDetailsActions.FETCH_DATA_FAILED,
    payload: {
        error
    }
});

export function fetchSparepartDetails(path) {
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchSparepartDetailsBegin());
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(path);
            dispatch(fetchSparepartDetailsSuccess(res.data));
        }
        catch (error) {
            return dispatch(fetchSparepartDetailsFailed(error));
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
  };

  export default function sparepartDetailsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case ActionTypes.sparePartDetailsActions.FETCH_DATA_BEGIN:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true,
          error: null
        };

      case ActionTypes.sparePartDetailsActions.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      const s = {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: action.payload.sparepart
      };
      console.log(s) 
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          data: action.payload.sparepart
        };

      case ActionTypes.sparePartDetailsActions.FETCH_DATA_FAILED:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.payload.error,
          data: []
        };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` did not fire?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings, yes, look like.

Comment: use redux logger and check what is happening

Comment: Are you sure it's the problem with `componentDidMount` ?? Have you tried `console.log()` in `componentDidMount` to confirm?

Comment: @AbhishekKumawat, yes, if I put console.log to ComponentDidMount, it's not used.

Comment: Are you going from one route to the same route while navigating? Or are the components on prev. and next route same?

Comment: @AbhishekKumawat, they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was probably related to some async stuff. And was fixed with this:

```
render() {
        if (this.props.details && this.props.details.length > 0) {
            return (
                <div className={styles.container}>
```